# iOS: Finding the total difference between 2 color's rgb values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, math, rgb

I was wondering if there is an existing math algorithm, that could help me get to the solution I need.

I have an input color:

- (229, 67, 99).

  [image]

I have 10 predefined colors and I want to find the color that closely matches the input color.

So far I have 3 NSArrays (reds, blues, greens). In each array I have 10 values. I'm currently using binary search to round my input color's values to the closest values that exist in each array.

For now I've gotten: r = 230, g = 126, b = 34 but this together doesn't make a predefined color, instead it makes a new color that is not predefined.

So what I did is I found the 3 predefined colors that have one of those values (the color closest to the red value, the color closest to the green value, and the color closest to the blue value.

- A. (**230**, 126, 34)

  [image]
- B. (142, **68**, 173)

  [image]
- C. (39, 174, **96**)

  [image]

The problem is that from my predefined colors, none of those 3 happen to be the closest. In fact overall its closes to another predefined color:

- D. (**231**, **76**, **60**)

  [image]

The absolute difference from all these colors are

- A. 1, 59, 65
- B. 87, 1, 74
- C. 190, 107, 2
- D. 2, 9, 3

Total Difference: (A=125, B=162, C=299, **D=14**)

So my question is... is there an existing algorithm to arrive at the smallest total difference? What's the best way to approach it?

I know how to get to 14, but my question is how can I compare total differences between all predefined colors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847092/given-an-rgb-value-what-would-be-the-best-way-to-find-the-closest-match-in-the-d. This maybe help

Comment: This definitely answered my question. Thank you so much @HoangVanHa

Comment: Could you post your answer please?