# Finding closest matching color name for an RGB value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have images RGB values in column 1-4 and I want to find closest RGB value from color definition in columns 8-10. Any advise please?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19T5eo3MmCup4dtVYNA-3hfQibtl9NvIBvS8mvpWSnDk/edit?usp=sharing

screenshot
[image]

Comment: Suggest you have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847092/given-an-rgb-value-what-would-be-the-best-way-to-find-the-closest-match-in-the-d . There are several different approaches, but it should be fairly straightforward to implement (say) the Euclidean Distance (sum of squared differences) one so I might post something on those lines later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) and the weights given [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100316195057/http://www.dfanning.com/ip_tips/color2gray.html):

`=sortn( K$2:K, 1, 0, 0.3 * (H$2:H - B2)^2 + 0.59 * (I$2:I - C2)^2 + 0.11 * (J$2:J - D2)^2, true )`

In the event your spreadsheet is in a locale that uses commas as decimal marks:

`=sortn( K$2:K; 1; 0; 0,3 * (H$2:H - B2)^2 + 0,59 * (I$2:I - C2)^2 + 0,11 * (J$2:J - D2)^2; true )`