# Does Unity have a way to convert a Color into it's string name equivalent from knownColor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, there are some colors predefined. Like `Color.red`. But there are only 8 of them, which doesn't even include orange! I already know that I can make any kind of color, but I need to get the string name of each color I.E. `Color.red => "red" or "Red"` and I'm wondering if theres a way to turn it into a C# KnownColor, and pull the name from that?

The use-case is that I have a radial menu color selector, and I'd like to display the name of each color below the color preview.

I am currently using this function:

```
private static String GetColorName(Color color, bool caps = false) {
    var colorProperty = typeof(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).FirstOrDefault(p=>(Color)(p.GetValue(p, null)) == color);
    return (colorProperty != null) ? caps ? string.Concat(colorProperty.Name[0].ToString().ToUpper(), colorProperty.Name.Substring(1)) : colorProperty.Name : color.ToString();
}
```

Which does work, but I want to expand it to use the KnownColors instead of the Unity Colors.

I would love to avoid needing to manage a dictionary or the like of colors.

---

I ended up doing something similar to the accepted answer. I split it into 2 parts. First, the dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Color> Colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor))
    .OfType<System.Drawing.KnownColor>()
    .ToList()
    .Where(c => !System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(c).IsSystemColor)
    .ToList()
    .ToDictionary(c=>c.ToString(), kc=>{
        System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(kc);
        return new Color(c.R, c.G, c.B, c.A);
    });
```

And then, I use this function to get it's name:

```
public string GetColorName(Color color, bool strict = false, bool lower = false) {
    if(color.r<=1 && color.g<=1 && color.b<=1 && color.a<=1){
        color *= 255;
    }
    string colorName = Colors.FirstOrDefault(x=>{
        return x.Value.r == color.r && x.Value.g == color.g && x.Value.b == color.b && (strict && x.Value.a == color.a);
    }).Key;
    return lower ? colorName.ToLower() : colorName;
}
```

Comment: There is no default way to get the "known" color name.  You would need to manage a dictionary or dynamically construct a string from the component values. There are 11 "known" colors, based on the documentation.

Comment: Right, but 2 of them are grey, and one is clear, which isn't a color at all

Comment: True, however they are colors that can be represented by the color struct and have the static accessors defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own dictionary via reflection, and store it in a static variable;

```cs
static Dictionary<Color, string> byName =
    typeof(Color)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
    .ToDictionary(p => (Color)p.GetValue(null), p => p.Name);
```

But only those exact hues will be in there.

If you wanted to name any colour, you could either take the above list, or maybe the [XKCD color survey results](https://xkcd.com/color/rgb/) and use [some function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1847112/4139809) to find the closest named colour. Perhaps via Pythagoras in either the RGB or HSV color space.

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately there is not. however, to solve what you are trying to achieve you can create a dictionary with the color's string name and the actual RGBA value of the color.

```
 IDicionary colorDictionary;

 void Start()
 {
    colorDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
    
    colorDictionary.Add("Black", Color.Black);
    colorDictionary.Add("White", Color.White);
    colorDictionary.Add("Orange", new Color(1f, 0.64f, 0f, 1f));
    colorDictionary.Add("Hot Pink", new Color(1f, 0.4f, 0.7f, 1f)); 
 }
```

Then from the dictionary you can display the color and the string.

Comment: I want to avoid this exactly, lol. The relations should already be made for me to leverage, re-declaring them seems... Bad to me

Comment: You declared the dictionary key/value pair in reverse.  The question is for a lookup from color to name. no biggie just wanted to point that out.